# How to make particle grains move across screen on render?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, video

So for a video I'm working on, I'm trying to achieve an older film effect so I followed this tutorial:

https://youtu.be/-1zr1zFQawA

I worked out surprisingly well for the most part but I noticed that neither the vertical lines or grain move across the screen in the video like they're supposed to.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Generated grain always looks fake. For a believable result I'd suggest use real film scans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Watch closely from 43:30 - he adds a keyframe to some node values and then adds a [noise modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/fmodifiers.html#noise) to the the keyed value.

[image]

A little later about 47:05, he adds a [translate node](https://www.blender.org/manual/compositing/types/distort/translate.html) and keys the x and y values to get some parts moving across the screen.