# Create non-animated, realistic film noise w/ scratches procedurally

Tags: node-editor, procedural

I know I'd probably use a combination of Noise Textures, but I have no idea how I could make it look realistic with varying combinations of random dots, scratch- and hair particles etc. I could only find some explanations on how to achieve standard film grain, nothing too detailed.

[image: Example]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84546 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123139 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68863

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do something like this.

[image: Film1]

The graph is comprised of mainly 2 parts - the "spots" and the "lines". Similar to what you were thinking, instead of Noise Textures, I used the distance output of Voronai Textures to make the "grain dots". I used varying levels of scale and randomness in addition to clamping the values with ColorRamps and using them to add a slight mustard-like hue (to match your image). I made 2 "fields" - one slightly dimmer than the other, and combined them using a Noise texture as a mix factor, so the end result would be a "patchy" combination of the two.

[image: Film2]

For the lines, I used a series of Wave Textures, offsetting some with Mapping Nodes and subtracting their values from each other, until I was left with some randomly spaced white lines that I then further darkened with another Noise Texture (so they aren't so evenly bright).

[image: Film3]

The last step, I used a Noise texture, heavily clamped to make the small white dots that are lightly "speckled"  around the image.

[image: Film4]

Finally I put them all together. I used an Emission Shader, as it makes sense that this is being emitted from a screen, and I ran the output through a HSV node first for finer control over the color and the brightness.

[image: Film5]

I'll post the file here, so you don't have to take the time to rebuild the graph yourself if you want to play with it.

File is here - [image]

Comment: I played around with your file and there are a lot of amazing possibilities. The reason I asked the question was because it's really hard to find free CC0 film grain overlay textures for programs like Photoshop in high resolution. To make the render look even more realistic I tried to 1) add hair/scratch particles by copying your White Dots group and 2) vertical lines by copying the Lines nodes and rotating them, but I'm new to Blender and not entirely satisfied with the result – I feel like the outcome would be perfect if you would give it a shot. Let us know, this is an amazing setup!

Comment: Yeah, I didn't go too detailed or add the vertical lines just because I was making a quick demo. However, I'm glad you found it helpful and would be happy to help you further. I'm working on a couple things right at the moment, but when I have a bit of time, I'll update the file with more detail. I'll post it here when I'm done.

Answer (score 6):

I can pretty quickly get a result like this using the compositor:

[image]

You can create textures using the Texture Properties Panel.  I identified three main features of your image to reproduce: a bed of noise, larger white flecks, and horizontal bands, trying as much as I can to avoid complete continuity.

You can recreate these features with a noise texture:

[image]

A musgrave texture:

[image]
[image]

Note that musgrave returns a range of -1 to 1, so it's easier to ramp it down to small black flecks and then invert in the compositor.

And this is what I actually used for the bands, but we're going to heavily modify this in the compositor.

[image]

You can choose these textures in the compositor from a Texture node, and mix them into your final image.  Here's what my node group looks like:

[image]

Note that we're stretching and squeezing the distorted noise texture quite a lot, and then applying a pretty harsh color ramp to it.  This gives us a more pleasing banding effect that doesn't have a hard cutoff and doesn't span the entire image.

I encourage you to experiment with more layers and colors to create the exact effect you want.